# Codeigniter return 404 page not found

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm developing web application using [Codeigniter](http://www.codeigniter.com). So far I have managed to run the application on my localhost. But when I upload the content unto the web hosting, I can't get it to run.

This is what I've tested so far:

1. strangely, I can call the controller **Welcome.php** which is the sample controller from codeigniter, and showing well.
2. But I can't call any other controller which my default controller eventhough I have set it in routes.php, config.php etc.

Below is my configuration for these files:

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'lokadok';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['upload/do_upload'] = 'upload/do_upload';
```

**config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = (( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && strlen($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])>0) ?
                    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : 'http://www.lokadok.co.id' );
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
```

and this is the **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/assets|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/assets|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My default controller is this:

**lokadok.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Lokadok extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        $data['is_login'] = $this->session->userdata(LOGGED_IN);            

        $specialty = $this->input->post('specialty', '');
        $address = $this->input->post('address', '');
        $doc_name = $this->input->post('doc_name', '');

        if ($specialty == '' && $address == '' && $doc_name == '') {
            $this->load->model('model_share');

            $data['custom_css'] = array(
                'style/custom/lokadok.css'
            );

            $data['sort_by'] = 1;
            $data['pop_specialties'] = $this->model_share->get_specialties(true);
            $data['specialties'] = $this->model_share->get_specialties();

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('lokadok_view');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
        } else {    
            redirect("search?specialty=$specialty&address=$address&doc_name=$doc_name&sort_by=1");
        }       
    }
}
?>
```

I have been looking for the answer for awhile and still couldn't figure it out. So if anyone can spot the error, I would really appreciate it.

To check on the location site you can go to:
www.lokadok.co.id which I expect to call my default controller.

and try to call http://www.lokadok.co.id/welcome which is strangely running well.

Thank you all, and hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: Try adding `Options -Multiviews +FollowSymLinks` to your .htaccess file

Comment: I saw that you wrote $config['base_url'] twice, is it a typo mistake or you actually did this ?

Comment: Capsule, i've added the line on top of the .htaccess, but still not working. any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies within your question :

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I think you need to enable mod_rewrite

**UPDATED**

Find your php.ini in

/etc/php.ini

Or here:

/etc/php/php.ini

/etc/php5/php.ini

Find the line with disable_functions, one of them likely being phpinfo. You'll need to remove phpinfo from the list of disabled functions in disabled_functions=

**IF UBUNTU THEN**

To enable the rewrite module, run "apache2 enable module rewrite" in terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

You need to restart the webserver to apply the changes:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I have checked around your suggestion and find out that by adding this RewriteEngine On will enable the mod_rewrite, Is this what you mean? (I'm using cpanel by the way), and this is the information where i got from https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-apache.361181/

Comment: Use phpinfo() function and search for mod_rewrite in Loaded Modules

Comment: I got this error message when running the phpinfo() Warning: phpinfo() has been disabled for security reasons in /home/global/public_html/lokadok.co.id/phpinfo.php on line 1, what does it mean?

Comment: i've enabled the phpinfo and you can check on http://www.lokadok.co.id/phpinfo.php please have a look and let me know

Comment: Your apache mod_rewrite is not enabled, you need to enable it. Let me know the OS on your server.